# How to refer inline created object later

Tags: java, gwt

For example:

```
VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
panel.add(new Label("Blalala"));
```

How can i get text from (new Label)??

Answer (score 3):

No. You have no clue of getting in current type of Label creation which is inline.

Separate the initialization to get the reference.

```
Label la= new Label("Blalala");
panel.add(la);
String text =la.getText();
```

And GWT specific answer for the problem is here.

[I blogged it here](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/07/getting-widgets-added-to-gwt-panels.html)

Here is the essential part

```
Iterator<Widget> arrayOfWidgets = panel.iterator();
    while (arrayOfWidgets.hasNext()){
      Widget ch = arrayOfWidgets.next();
      if (ch instanceof Label) {
      //Do something 
      }
    }
```

And I prefer the first way.

[**Complete GWT Solution.....**](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/07/getting-widgets-added-to-gwt-panels.html)

Answer (score 0):

If thats the only widget on the panel you can do:-`((Label)panel.getWidget(0)).getText();`